# KMeans scatter plot on macbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, k-means

I was trying to plot a scatter plot for a dataset with 4000 rows. I am running Jupyter Notebook on a macbook. I found it took more than five minutes for the scatter plot to appear in the Jupyter notebook. My notebook was recently bought and it is 2.3Ghz intel core i5 and the memory is 8GB.

I have two questions:

- why it took so long?
- why the plot was so congested (for example, all x scales appeared small and they came together and could not be read clearly) and not very clear. The dataset is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datascienceinc/learn-data-science/master/Introduction-to-K-means-Clustering/Data/data_1024.csv

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

df= pd.read_csv('/users/kyaw/Downloads/data_1024.csv')
df = df.join(df['Driver_ID'].str.split(expand=True))
df = df.drop(["Driver_ID"], axis=1)
df.columns=['Driver_ID','Distance_Feature','Speeding_Feature']

f1 = df['Distance_Feature'].values
f2 = df['Speeding_Feature'].values

X=np.array(list(zip(f1,f2)))

fig=plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(10,8)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X) 

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=kmeans.labels_, cmap='rainbow')  
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0] ,kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1], color='black')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run your code and it didn't work. I make the following corrections

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline  --> Removed this inline, maybe is here due to jupyter
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans    

df= pd.read_csv('./data_1024.csv',sep='\t' )  #indicate the separator as tab.  
#remove the other instructions that are useless

f1 = df['Distance_Feature'].values 
f2 = df['Speeding_Feature'].values

X=np.array(list(zip(f1,f2)))

fig=plt.gcf() 
fig.set_size_inches(10,8) 
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X) 

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=kmeans.labels_, cmap='rainbow')    
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0] ,kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1], color='black') 
plt.show()
```

I got this image
[image]

Comment: I tried to rerun your corrections indicating the file in my directory. df= pd.read_csv('/users/kyaw/Downloads/data_1024.csv',sep='\t' ). but it shows KeyError: 'Distance_Feature'

Comment: how shall I put legend in my graph based on colors?

Comment: you can try plt.legend()

Comment: I tried but it did not work. it said, "No handles with labels found to put in legend."